# What can be the procedure/code to remove "string expression" from a file using Apache Pig?

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

```
A = load '/home/wrdtest.txt';

B = foreach A generate flatten(TOKENIZE((chararray)$0)) as word;

C = filter B by word != 'the';

D = group C by word;

E = foreach D generate COUNT(C) as count, group as word;

F = order E by count desc;

store F into '/tmp/sample_data20';
```

I just want to filter the text . The 3rd step filters the text and removes 'the' from text file. But i want to remove a set of 499 words (stop words) from the text. I tried to use '|' (as OR ) like :

```
C = filter B by word != 'the|and|or'...but it didnt work.
```

Can you please suggest on this and may i include a text file like (stopwords.txt) in order to remove the stop words.

I am a naive user of Pig

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like removing stop words is complicated enough that it is not going to be in the built-in functions. You'll need to write a [user-defined function](http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.9.1/udf.html), which is quite simple to do.

```
-- load the data line by line
lines = LOAD 'datafile.txt' USING TextLoader() AS (line:chararray);

-- apply some sort of UDF that returns the exact line without the stop words
nostop = FOREACH lines GENERATE myudfs.removestop(line);

-- store the data out
STORE nonstop INTO 'datafile_nostop.txt';
```

Pushing that list of yours out to the tasks is another story. If the list is relatively small,  in the order of thousands, you can bake the stop words into your code (i.e., hardcoding the list) so that it has it available. Otherwise, you could use the Distributed Cache to push the file out.

---

With the more information you provided, I can suggest an alternative approach. My above approach of using a UDF is still valid, though.

This new approach will involve you loading your other file, then effectively doing an anti-join to remove things that match the list. You need to make sure `stopwords.txt` has one word per line in order for this to work. To do the anti-join (i.e., keep the things the list that do not match the other list), I'll do a [left outer join](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_%28SQL%29#Left_outer_join) (using [replicated](http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.9.1/perf.html#Replicated-Joins)), then filter out where the stop word column is null (i.e., it did not have a stop word that matched).

```
A = load '/home/wrdtest.txt';

-- load the stop words list
SW = load '/home/stopwords.txt' as (stopword:chararray);    

B = foreach A generate flatten(TOKENIZE((chararray)$0)) as word;

-- join the data with a left outer join
-- using replicated should be done with the right relation (SW) is small
SW2 = join B by word LEFT OUTER, SW by stopword USING 'replicated';

-- filter out where the stopword is null, meaning it is not in the stopword list
C = filter SW2 by stopword IS NULL;

-- remove the stopword column that we don't need.
C = foreach C generate word;

D = group C by word;

E = foreach D generate COUNT(C) as count, group as word;

F = order E by count desc;

store F into '/tmp/sample_data20';
```

Comment: Please suggest me on the latest edit which i have made in the summary. I have provided the code which i am currently working on.

Comment: I have executed the code. But the results seems to be the same. My stopwords.txt structure 

a

the 

is....

one word per line.

Answer (score 2):

I used the above solution by Donald Miner.

I modified the relation about JOIN part as the following

```
SW2 = join B by word LEFT, SW by stopword;
```

and works for me.