# Apache Pig: Removing Stopwords from Bag of Token Tuples?

Tags: join, apache-pig, stop-words

I'm trying to remove stopwords from a relation of job descriptions, using Pig. Yet I'm not able to join two relations to match the stopwords to my text.

My data is a csv file with two entries per row:
[image: Job Descriptions]

I also have a list of 630 English stopwords:

[image: Stopwords]

In Pig, I'm loading both files and transforming the first one in the following way:

```
 jobs10 = load 'data/hw4/jobs/20140213_descriptions10.csv' using PigStorage(',') as (id:chararray,descr:chararray);
 descrFlat = foreach jobs10 generate id,flatten(TOKENIZE(descr));
 stopwords = load 'data/hw4/stopwords-en.txt' using PigStorage('\n') as (word:chararray);
```

`descrFlat` now looks like this:

```
grunt> describe descrFlat
descrFlat: {id: chararray,bag_of_tokenTuples_from_descr::token: chararray}
```

Similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8819440/what-can-be-the-procedure-code-to-remove-string-expression-from-a-file-using-a) and [this](https://www.quora.com/What-can-be-the-procedure-code-to-remove-string-expression-from-a-file-using-Apache-Pig) example, I'm now trying to OUTER JOIN the two files...

```
J = JOIN stopwords BY $0 RIGHT OUTER, descrFlat BY $0;
```

...resulting in the following structure for `J`:

```
grunt> describe J
J: {stopwords::word: chararray,descrFlat::id: chararray,descrFlat::bag_of_tokenTuples_from_descr::token: chararray}
```

Yet this isn't the desired result to use `K = FILTER J BY $0 IS NULL;` on; the data is just gibberish:

```
grunt> dump J
```

This is probably due to the fact that I'm working with a bag of token tuples instead of the simple tuples in the aforementioned examples.

[image: Gibberish]

Answer (score 0):

I found my mistake. The following is referring to the first column in descrFlat, whereas it should really be referring to the second column (`$1`), which holds the words. Also, removing unnecessary punctuation helped.

```
J = JOIN stopwords BY $0 RIGHT OUTER, descrFlat BY $0;
```